# swift JSON calls, closures using usergrid IOS SDK and multiple calls

Tags: ios, swift, handler, completion, usergrid

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 for an IOS app, the latest usergrid SDK 2.1.3. I am having troubles with the best way to make multiple calls to usergrid to validate data before finally creating a new entity. The problem is the code is continuing before the validation on 1 or more users is complete. The validation MUST happen before I have add the users to the entity that I want to create.

Usergrid has the following performRequest for all Data calls :

```
    func performRequest(_ request:UsergridRequest, completion:UsergridResponseCompletion?) {
        session.dataTask(with: request.buildNSURLRequest()) { [weak self] (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let usergridResponse = UsergridResponse(client:self?.client, data: data, response: response as? HTTPURLResponse, error: error as NSError?)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion?(usergridResponse)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The completion handler returns too late. (Very common theme).

I want to do this :
- with a list of users, check whether they exist already. Usergrid API: UsergridUser.checkAvailable
- Add user if they don't exist
- Create a new group
- Add the users to the new group

```
static func checkAvailabilty(username:String, email:String, completion: @escaping (AuthResult) -> ()) {
//
// other checking
//  error: UsergridResponseError?

UsergridUser.checkAvailable(email, username: username, completion: { (error,avail) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        completion(.failure(error))
    } else {
        completion(.success(avail))
    }
  })
}
```

And in the View controller :

```
UsergridManager.checkAvailabilty(username: "jim", email: "") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let granted) :
        if granted {
            print("user is available")
        } else {
            print("user is NOT available")
        }
    case .failure(let error): print(error?.errorDescription)
    }

}
```

The View controller continue's before I know whether the user is available. Should the performRequest be changed? I have attempted DispatchGroup, attempted a Dispatch.main.sync - but would like another option rather than nesting the completion handlers for all these calls.

Comment: What does `The View controller continue's` mean? I don't see any UI code at all. Generally, you need to 1) Accept user input to create. 2) Validate data. 3a) Notify UI that data is invalid or 3b) Create user. 4) Notify UI that user was created.

Comment: Matt - I did not show all the validation code on purpose - attempted to outline the steps instead. The View controller continue's means - that with each successive validation backend call ( to Usergrid) which is put in the background - the rest of the code continue's processing. So this happens : 1) validate user 1 2) validate user 2 3) create new user 4) create group 5) add all users to the group. But since the Usergrid call places the completion handler on the DispatchQueue.main.async - step 5 begins before steps 1-3 finish. Thank you - John